# Jest: Cannot read property 'secondary' of undefined - after MUI upgrade from V4 toV5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

We upgraded MUI from v4 to v5 and we have UI tests which started failing. Error is:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'secondary' of undefined (I added comment to which line in code this refers)`

Test example:

```js
     describe('<AnonDragNDropFileUpload />', () => {
      it('should render', () => {
        const blob = () => {
          return new File(['Test string'], 'Test file.txt');
        };
        const fileSet: AnonFileSet = {
          originalFile: { get: blob, set: () => undefined },
          compressedFile: { get: () => undefined, set: () => undefined },
        };
        const result = render(<AnonDragNDropFileUpload fileSet={fileSet} downloadFileAction={jest.fn()} clearFileAction={jest.fn()} />);
        expect(result).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

Code:

```js
import { Paper } from '@mui/material';
import { green, red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { lighten, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles';
import { JobInputFileTypeEnum } from 'app/api';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import { AnonFileSet } from '.';

const useDropZoneStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  dragndropZone: {
    backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.8), // <-- this line fails
    width: '100%',
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: green[100],
    width: '100%',
  },
}));

interface Props {
  fileSet: AnonFileSet;
  clearFileAction: (fileType?: JobInputFileTypeEnum) => void;
  downloadFileAction: () => void;
}

export const AnonDragNDropFileUpload: React.FC<Props> = ({ fileSet, clearFileAction, downloadFileAction }) => {
  const classes = useDropZoneStyles();
  const [fileLabel, setFileLabel] = useState('');

  const onDrop = useCallback(async (acceptedFiles: File[]) => {
    setFileLabel(fileSet.originalFile.get()?.name ?? '');
    fileSet.originalFile.set(acceptedFiles[0]);
  }, []);

  const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop, multiple: false, accept: '.csv' });
  const { ref, ...rootProps } = getRootProps();

  const handleDeleteFile = () => {
    acceptedFiles.splice(
      acceptedFiles.findIndex((x) => x.name === fileSet.originalFile.get()?.name),
      1,
    );
    clearFileAction();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setFileLabel(fileSet.originalFile.get()?.name ?? '');
  }, [fileSet.originalFile.get()]);

  if (fileSet.originalFile.get())
    return (
      <Paper variant="outlined">
        <div className="flex px-8 py-32 justify-center">
          <div className="flex">
            <a style={{ color: '#888888', textDecoration: 'underline', cursor: 'default' }}>{fileLabel}</a>
            <p className="mx-4">&nbsp;</p>
            <a onClick={handleDeleteFile} style={{ color: red[600], cursor: 'pointer' }} role="link">
              {'[Clear File]'}
            </a>
            <p className="mx-4">&nbsp;</p>
            {fileSet.compressedFile?.get() && (
              <a onClick={downloadFileAction} style={{ color: green[600], cursor: 'pointer' }} role="link">
                {'[Download File]'}
              </a>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );

  return (
    <Paper {...rootProps} className={classes.dragndropZone} variant="outlined">
      <div className="flex px-8 py-32 justify-center">
        <input {...getInputProps()} name="customerCSVFilename" placeholder="CSV File"/>
        <p>{fileLabel}</p>
      </div>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

What I've tried so far:

- Checked if ThemeProvider is available
- Added custom theme just to the code block which fails

All other tests which are testing hooks or custom logic (like pure TypeScript) are working without any issues, but it seems that somehow using styles from MUI is not working. When I remove these lines, test is passing, so my guess it has something with MUI `makeStyles`.
Any ideas? Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a mocked component, wrapped inside a `ThemeProvider` instance:

```
import theme from './path/to/your/theme'

const MockAnonDragNDropFileUpload = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <AnonDragNDropFileUpload {...props} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

To mock the component using the existing `theme` you could separate its declaration into a distinct file:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    ...
});

export default theme;
```

Then use the mocked instance in the tests:

```
describe('<AnonDragNDropFileUpload />', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    ...
    const result = render(
      <MockAnonDragNDropFileUpload
        fileSet={fileSet}
        downloadFileAction={jest.fn()}
        clearFileAction={jest.fn()}
      />
    );
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to mock it if I can avoid that, because I want to have like a real theme used in a test (or tests). Mocking will not tell the story, especially if we update theme colors in the future or add dark mode

Comment: @RadeTomovic Ok, so I think you should separate the `theme` declaration into a distinct file and use it both on your regular application and your tests. You need to wrap the component inside the `ThemeProvider`, otherwise, the test will not run correctly. See edited answer.

Comment: Nice, this was a workaround for me, you can just create the mock component in your test file and render that.